# How to get data from array result in laravel?

Tags: laravel

How i get **tx_ref** data in laravel controller?
When I go to this variable

```
$data = Flutterwave::verifyTransaction($transactionID);
```

The show the result below.

```html
array:3 [▼
  "status" => "success"
  "message" => "Transaction fetched successfully"
  "data" => array:21 [▼
    "id" => 2630812
    "tx_ref" => "flw_16371364716194b85744801"
    "flw_ref" => "FLW-MOCK-00329ed793a3e0928c4259ebbf7068da"
    "device_fingerprint" => "62f14a8a3c77ddf2b14c77021250564c"
    "amount" => 10
    "currency" => "GBP"
    "charged_amount" => 10
    "app_fee" => 0.38
    "merchant_fee" => 0
    "processor_response" => "Approved. Successful"
    "auth_model" => "VBVSECURECODE"
    "ip" => "52.209.154.143"
    "narration" => "CARD Transaction "
    "status" => "successful"
    "payment_type" => "card"
    "created_at" => "2021-11-17T08:12:46.000Z"
    "account_id" => 168506
    "card" => array:7 [▼
      "first_6digits" => "553188"
      "last_4digits" => "2950"
      "issuer" => " CREDIT"
      "country" => "NIGERIA NG"
      "type" => "MASTERCARD"
      "token" => "flw-t1nf-8a806dc225adf0e584c039a473d54c6b-m03k"
      "expiry" => "09/32"
    ]
    "meta" => array:1 [▼
      "__CheckoutInitAddress" => "https://ravemodal-dev.herokuapp.com/v3/hosted/pay/853bfc044b27ab3bf85b"
    ]
    "amount_settled" => 9.62
    "customer" => array:5 [▼
      "id" => 1443167
      "name" => "Fin Padi"
      "phone_number" => "01751414572"
      "email" => "app@myfinpadi.com"
      "created_at" => "2021-11-16T22:46:54.000Z"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Basically I need to get "flw_16371364716194b85744801" that avilable on "tx_ref" in "data" . Please see the array result and help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data using `dd($data['data']['tx_ref']);`

Comment: you have missed `"data" => array:21 [▼`

Comment: Oh, yes. I stand corrected. Overlooked that one. Thanks.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: @MSU Rubel try `dd($data['data']['tx_ref']);` instead

Comment: @MSURubel try what fufu sayd, if don't work, use `pluck()` or `value()`